# Insert only 1 data into a cell using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How i can insert only 1 record into a cell. using Linq. I am using EF6

I want to insert "Y" or "N"   into a cell to check whether user is Active or not, using linq. I want to insert into "USER" table, which have all the user detail including "IsActive" field. Without retrieving all the user details i just want to insert "Y" or "N" into the "USER" table.

Comment: Please post your code otherwise it's impossible to help. LINQ is a query language, it doesn't insert data. Inserting is the job of Entity Framework. If you only create a single object, only one record will be created. What have you tried and what is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
using(var ctx = new YourEntities())
{
  var user = ctx.USER.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "someName");
  user.IsActive = "y"; //btw it should be boolean not a varchar
  entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: single column Update value in data base

Comment: @MukeshKalgude what do You mean ? Is this code not updating a single column ? All other columns won't be touched

Comment: Read question. which have all the user detail including "IsActive" field.

Comment: Man, You better read it again "USER" table, which have all the user detail including "IsActive" field" it was just a description of a table.